# Animation Nodes: Weird invalid network issue

Tags: animation-nodes

I have two similar loop network to control two different objects with two matrix lists.

When I connect one math node to control the scales of both objects loop in the same time it show me the "invalid network" error.

I don't understand why. The task I ask for seem to me very ordinary.

[image]

...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another a parameter to your loops and use this as your input parameter, like this:

[image]

Generally loops and subprograms cannot use the same nodes. They are so called "closed" systems. So if you wanna reuse something, make a subprogram out of it and use it or use iterators/parameters.

Comment: It work perfectly with your method if I add a float in "new parameter" in the loop input node.Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

There should be a problems panel on the left n-menu in Animation nodes. There you can see whats causing the problem.